# Изометрия. Расчеты

Tags: javascript, css, математика, canvas

Всем привет! В своем проекте я хочу сделать изометрию, но никак не могу понять как там выполняются расчеты. Заходил на разные сайты, вот, что на них говорят делать:

```
var tilePositionX = (x - y) * width,
    tilePositionY = (x + y) * height / 2;

где x и y координаты тайлов на нашей сетке.
```

Вроде бы все хорошо расставилось
[image: Вроде бы все хорошо расставилось]

Но, когда я начинаю вращать тайлы (а на сайтах написано, что нужно повернуть тайл на 45 градусов), то у меня выходит следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Повернулись и тайлы, и сама сетка.
Тут-то я начинаю теряться: пытаюсь сдвинуть тайлы по диагонали вниз - у меня они куда-то наверх уходят. Ничего не пойму. Как в этом разобраться? Объясните, пожалуйста :)

Comment: Для вращения фигуры,  используется следующее преобразование: `x' = x*cos(a) + y*sin(a); y'=x*sin(a)+y*cos(a)`  Почитайте *полярная система координат*. Вращение происходит относительно (0,0) если центр вращения нужно сместить - ф-ла усложняется.

Comment: `x' = ((x - x0)*cos(a) + (y-y0)*sin(a))+x0; y'=((x-x0)*sin(a)+(y-y0)*cos(a))+y0;` Вот это вращение со смещённым центром (x0,y0), т.е. x0,y0 - это центр вашей фигуры (если вы её хотите вращать вокруг себя).